# Cassandra UnavailableException()

Tags: cassandra

Exception in thread "main" **UnavailableException()**

> at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:16485)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:916)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:890)
>     at WordCountSetup.main(Unknown
>   Source)

Hi, I got this error while running a job in cassandra. can anyone help me how to get those class files.
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 11):

[UnavailableException](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API) means "too many replicas are down."

Comment: In my case I had invalid data center names in my `strategy_options` parameter. Once I fixed that context parameter, it worked again!

Comment: I get this error even when all the nodes in my cluster are up (as shown in nodetool status output). What can be the possible reason?

Answer (score 3):

Usually this error comes when there is some issue with the replication setting of your key space. 
Few possibilities

1. You have used network topology replication strategy but you do not have a cluster set up
   Then change the below:
   `placement_strategy = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy' AND strategy_options={datacenter1:1};`   to-> `placement_strategy = 'SimpleStrategy' AND strategy_options={replication_factor:1};`may
2. You may have your data center name mismatched in the ring vs in your keyspace definition
3. May be your ring is down.

For 2 and 3 use 
`nodetool ring`
command to find out how your ring is set up. Then accordingly update the keyspace definition.