# Apache Cassandra. UnavailableException While Trying to insert a record

Tags: cassandra

I am very new to Cassandra, and some how configured it. I was following [This Link](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted)
.
Everything was fine. But in the end when I am trying to insert a record, it gives me the following exception. Today since afternoon I am trying to fix this. Googled a lot, but could not reach anywhere.

Any help on this will be greatly appretiated.

```
[default@DEMO] set Users[1234][name] = scott;
null
UnavailableException()
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$insert_result.read(Cassandra.java:16077)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_insert(Cassandra.java:801)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.insert(Cassandra.java:785)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeSet(CliClient.java:909)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:222)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:201)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:328)
[default@DEMO]
```

Thank you
Achyuth

Comment: I think the problem is with replication_factor<br/>
Give this a try <br/><br/>

[default@DEMO] create keyspace  DEMO
with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'
and strategy_options = [{replication_factor:1}];
<br/><br/>
instead of 
<br/>
[default@unknown] create keyspace DEMO; <br/>

Comment: Can you paste the output of 'nodetool ring'?

Comment: @Achyuth I've updated the wiki page to include the strategy options when creating a keyspace, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnavailableException() in Apache-Cassandra 0.8.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011403/unavailableexception-in-apache-cassandra-0-8-2)

Comment: @Achyuth, I had similar issue and your comment solved it.

Comment: Checkout this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25386823/808096)

Answer (score 2):

this is old one, I want to share my experience.

I had same issue when I was setting the qa environment. Every thing configured fine:  including : cassandra-topology.properties.  But the nodetool ring display the unknown DC value for all nodes since the default is set UNKNOWN.  That told me that the cassandra-topology.properties is not right in some way. After tried several things still no luck, I decided to create my own cassandra-topology.properties file and re-type every thing with vi, then it starts fine.

So if you have issue, run nodetool ring first to see if the DC set is what it should be.